# Dockerfile with LAMP running (Ubuntu)

Tags: docker, lamp

I'm trying to create a Docker (LAMP) image with the following

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN  apt-get update \
  && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y \
    apache2 \
    mysql-server \
    php7.0 \
    php7.0-bcmath \
    php7.0-mcrypt
COPY start-script.sh /root/
RUN chmod +x /root/start-script.sh && /root/start-script.sh
```

**start-script.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
service mysql start
a2enmod rewrite
service apache2 start
```

I build it with:

```
docker build -t resting/ubuntu .
```

Then run it with:

```
docker run -it -p 8000:80 -p 5000:3306 -v $(pwd)/html:/var/www/html resting/ubuntu bash
```

The problem is, the `MYSQL` and `Apache2` service are not started.
If I run `/root/start-script.sh` manually in the container, port 80 maps fine to port 8000, but I couldn't connect to `MYSQL` with `127.0.0.1:5000`.

How can I ensure that the services are running when I spin up a container with the image, and map MYSQL out to my host machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the execution of the script to a `CMD` instruction.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN  apt-get update \
  && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y \
    apache2 \
    mysql-server \
    php7.0 \
    php7.0-bcmath \
    php7.0-mcrypt
COPY start-script.sh /root/
RUN chmod +x /root/start-script.sh 
CMD /root/start-script.sh
```

Althought this works, this is not the right way to manage containers. You should have one container for your `Apache2` and another one for `MySQL`.

Take a look to this article that build a LAMP stack using Docker-Compose: https://www.kinamo.be/en/support/faq/setting-up-a-development-environment-with-docker-compose

Comment: Have tried `CMD`, but the container exits after execution.  
The link helped to break up the containers. But somehow `MYSQL` is not talking to `PHP` container, probably post another question after a few more tries.

Comment: The container exits because the process finished, since `service apache2 start` executes `Apache2` in background. A container lives since it has a main process to execute. If you want it to stay alive, exec `Apache2` or `MySQL` in foreground.

Answer (score 0):

you need multiple images - one for each service or app.

A Docker container is not a virtual machine in which you run an entire stack. It is a virtual application, running one primary process.

If you need php, apache and mysql, then you will need 3 docker containers. one for your php app, one for apache and one for mysql.

Comment: Right, trying to put them into separate containers now.

Comment: No, you don't. You may run the entire stack in a single container if you wish so or if that is your requirement.